# Obtaining a thin/compact SVD

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm using `SingularValueDecomposition` for a least-squares regression, the instruction that works fine for what I need is

```
SingularValueDecomposition[X,Length[SingularValueList[X]]]
```

Is there a way to do the same thing but without calling `SingularValueList` as I suppose similar computations are done two times in `SingularValueDecomposition` and `SingularValueList` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the full svd, then use the number of nonzero singular values to recover the thin svd.

```
thinSVD[mat_] := Module[
  {u, w, v, wprime, len},
  {u, w, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[mat];
  wprime = DeleteCases[w, {_?(# == 0 &) ..}];
  len = Length[wprime];
  wprime = wprime[[All, 1 ;; len]];
  {u[[All, 1 ;; len]], wprime, v[[All, 1 ;; len]]}
  ]
```

Here is a fairly standard example.

```
In[66]:= m = N[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}];
{ut, wt, vt} = thinSVD[m]
Chop[ut.wt.Transpose[vt] - m](*want zeros*)

Out[67]= {{{-0.214837, -0.887231}, {-0.520587, -0.249644}, {-0.826338,
    0.387943}}, {{16.8481, 0.}, {0., 1.06837}}, {{-0.479671, 
   0.776691}, {-0.572368, 0.0756865}, {-0.665064, -0.625318}}}

Out[68]= {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: Daniel, would `{(0 | 0.) ..}` work as well?

Comment: Often. If the matrix is machine numbers or integers then probably yes. Though I'm not certain the exact case will always figure out it has exact zeros (I guess it will). But don't expect it to work if bignums are used.

Comment: I think this could be improved by letting your `thinSVD[]` function take a `Tolerance` option as well. From that, you'll need to modify the `DeleteCases[]` line...